# Underline Color Word Web Add-in without Font Color

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-web-addins

I am working on Word web addin OfficeJS, I wanna change my underline color to red.
Is it possible to change the color of underline without affecting the font color ?
Attached my code below:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

            var searchResults = context.document.body.search(searchResult, { ignorePunct: true });
            context.load(searchResults, 'font');
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {

                    searchResults.items[i].font.color = 'red';                   
                    searchResults.items[i].font.underline = 'wave';  
                }
                return context.sync();
            });
        })
```

Comment: use `text-decoration-color`

Comment: @Adelin Does Word support that? (Remember, this isn't a browser environment.)

Comment: Good point. not sure. try it: `searchResults.items[i].style.textDecorationColor = "blue"`

Comment: Not working, man @Adelin

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create a custom character style with the underline color set to red. Give the style a name. The following code works for me. "StyleZZ" is a character style which specifies an underline font with red underline color. In all other respects it is default font.

```
var searchResults = context.document.body.search(searchResult, { ignorePunct: true });
searchResults.load("style");
return context.sync().then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
       searchResults.items[i].style = "StyleZZ";
    }
    return context.sync();
});
```

Notice that you don't have to load everything on the `searchResults` object, only the `style` property.

Comment: here, How you are loading the OOXML and getting the style ? I don't find any reference for dynamically inserting style for texts those are all existing already inside the document ?